# Combine multiple row values in a column for grouby

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

My Table has the followiing:

---

```
I   Place   ID
1   KARNATAKA   3         
2   KARNATAKA   5         
3   ANDHRA  3         
4   ANDHRA  4         
9   TAMILNADU   2         
6   TAMILNADU   5         
7   TAMILNADU   1         
8   TAMILNADU   4
```

Another Table:

```
Id  FirstName   SecondName
1           Ram         N         
2           Sita        K         
3           Bootha      MU        
4           Krishnan    S         
5           Hari        M         
6           Mehta       A         
7           Rahul       C         
8           Vamsi       M         
9           Badri       S
```

I am looking for output like the following:

```
Place    FirstName
KARNATAKA    Bootha, Hari
ANDHRA       Bootha, Krishnan
```

and likewise the thrid row.

Basically, it combines "STUFFS" in the 2nd column.

I try queries like the below, but its not working.

```
select ad.Place, STUFF((SELECT ', '+ FirstName FROM Associate a INNER JOIN Address Ad on a.Id = Ad.ID 
FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 1, '') 
From Address ad inner join Associate a
on ad.ID = a.Id
group by ad.Place
```

It just needs a slight correction, please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have too many joins.  This is tricky, because the join between the two tables is by `id`, but you are aggregating at a different level.  So, you do need both a `join` and a correlation condition in the subquery:

```
select ad.Place,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + a.FirstName
              FROM Associate a join
                   Address ad2
                   on a.Id = ad2.Id
              WHERE ad2.Place = ad.Place
              FOR XML PATH ('')
             ) , 1, 2, '') 
From Address ad
group by ad.Place;
```

As a minor point, your arguments to `stuff()` (`1, 1`) would leave a space at the beginning of the concatenated strings.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, wonderful, I removed "ON" from your query, it worked :) :) I agree with you on space. Today is first time I come across STUFF :)